# Two differing questions on probabilities (lottery and combination)

Tags: statistics, permutations

Question 1

I want to play the lottery. The overall chance of winning just the jackpot in a 6/49 lottery is 1 in 13,983,816. The math for that is:

1 * (49*48*47*46*45*44) = 10,068,347,520

divided by

1 * (6*5*4*3*2*1) = 720

The logic: You’re taking 1 ball 6 times and the balls are mutually exclusive, so your chances of a random number are 1/49, followed by 1/48, followed by 1/47, etc. Since you only draw 6 balls, we stop at 1/44. Then we need to consider that the order does not matter (we’re not talking about the sequence, just the probability of the numbers themselves regardless of the order they show up) we need to divide the total by the number of sequences each group of numbers could be drawn in. To get the total number of ways the sequences could be drawn in, we do the same form of equation (1/6, followed by 1/5, etc.—again since there are only 6 balls) and use that total to pare down your initial number of chances that isn’t constrained by eliminating sequence.

**So here’s the question: If you buy two 6/49 lottery tickets, what are your percentage odds of winning the Jackpot?**

Question 2

You are designing an interface for a locker system for a client. You’ve decided that in order to open a locker, all a customer needs to do is show up to the digital screen that interfaces with the physical lockers, and type in a 5 digit code. Your client is scared that this isn’t secure, so you do some math:

Suppose that there are 35 unique active codes, that if typed in will open a locker.

You know that since these codes are sequence specific, the order each number is entered is very important (unlike the lottery question above). So you figure since you have a keypad that covers numbers 0-9, you have 10 different numbers possible in many sequences and many combinations. That comes out to:

1 * (10*10*10*10*10) = 100,000 possible combinations

Again, that above calculation includes different sequences. A 7 selected as the first number doesn’t mean you can’t also have a 7 as the third number.

So if you have 35 active codes, that means there’s a 35/100,000 chance that a number can be randomly selected. That’s roughly 1/2,857.

**So here’s the question. Assuming the odds are exactly 1/2,858 of guessing a correct combination, what are your percentage odds of guessing a correct combination if you try two unique codes back to back?**

Not sure if I'm right, but for answers, I got:

1. 0.0350%
2. 0.00001430%

Comment: The person has tried, but not fully succeeded, and is not sure if the answers are right. So why the closure votes ??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it consists of multiple questions which should be asked separately.

Comment: In my opinion, the two questions amount to one  about the distinction between two slightly different scenarios

Comment: It also mystifies me as to why the question is viewed as not about math. There must be scores of lottery problems strewn around on this site !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your answers is correct, but you have mixed up answers.

$Q1$ Each ticket has the same chance of winning, and only one ticket can win,
so $Pr = \dfrac{2}{13,983,816}, \approx 0.00001430\%$

$Q2$ Either you succeed on first try, or try a different number and succeed on second try,
so $Pr = \dfrac{35}{100,000} + \dfrac{99965}{100,000}\cdot\dfrac{34}{99,999}, \approx 0.069\% $

*PS*

Another way to compute the second one is to find the complement of failing both times, viz.

$Pr = 1 - \dfrac{99965}{100,000}\cdot\dfrac{99964}{99,999}$